# How generic are Cayley graphs of non-Abelian groups with logarithmic girth?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Given a non-Abelian group $G$ I want to choose a symmetric generating set $S \subset G$ such that $Cay(G,S)$ has girth logarithmic in the size of the set. I want to know,

- For which $G$ can the existence of such a $S$ be guaranteed?
- For which $G$ will any arbitrary choice of a large enough set $S$ guarantee this property?
- For which $G$ will a $S$ of large enough size picked uniformly at random be likely to ensure this property?

---

Some searching through literature tells me that $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ satisfies all the above properties. Any reference for proofs of this particular example would also be helpful. Though my question is more like looking for generic patterns.

---

I can't make this intuition precise but my gut feeling is that all these properties are true if the dimension of the smallest irrep of $G$ is of the order of some root of the size of the group. (like for $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the smallest irrep is of dimension order of cube-root of the size of the group)

One might also be reminded of things like,
http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i1r62/pdf
http://www.eatcs.org/beatcs/index.php/beatcs/article/view/209

Comment: Every expander graph have logarithmic diameter (which follows from say the expander mixing lemma).

There is indeed relation to representation theory which was termed by Gowers as quasi-randomness, see the following post by Tao - https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/254b-notes-3-quasirandom-groups-expansion-and-selbergs-316-theorem/

Comment: Is there any reference for the proof of this property for SL_2(F_p) ? Any reference for techniques about proving lower bounds or calculating the girth of non-Abelian Cayley graphs?

Comment: @Anirbit: The Ramanujan graphs based on $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ have logarithmic girth, see the 1988 by A. Lubotzky, R. Phillips and P. Sarnak in Combinatorica.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But its not clear to me that this LPS paper actually proves this logarithmic girth property. They take a totally eigenvalue approach to get their sharp numbers. I am looking for techniques to prove high girth. Let me put up a separate question about it.

Comment: @Anirbit: Theorem 3.4 in LPS is exactly the logarithmic girth!!!

Comment: Then let me check again!

Comment: http://math1.math.huji.ac.il/~alexlub/PAPERS/ramanujan%20graphs/ramanujanGraphs.pdf

Comment: @user6818: If $G$ is solvable of solvability degree $n$, then the girth of any Cayley graph is at most $4^n$ (= the length of an $n$-iterated commutator in the generators of a free group). So you may forget about solvable groups.

Comment: ^Can you give a reference to this? It seems very hard to find examples of such girth calculation for Cayley graphs!

Comment: @Asaf Looking at that Terence Tao's article it seems that they cannot guarantee any good spectral gap from the property of quasirandomness. Is that right?

Comment: @Anirbit , the quasirandomness is used only in the final part of the Bourgain-Gamburd argument, I haven't said it is the only one (actually the main one, growth lemma which was proven by Helfgott from arithmetic combinatorics is used in the middle part). See the other posts in this course by Tao.
And the problem that B-G solved was a conjecture by Lubotzky (and Weiss) about thin-groups being expanders (not formulated in this language obviously), hence proving any kind of spectral gap. Obviously when good arithmetical reasoning enters (Ramanujan) you can get much better bounds than those.

Comment: Yes. But has anyone been able to show any spectral-gaps from quasirandomness? (apart from saying that it is non-zero)

Comment: Or can this quansirandomness property be converted into a method to find an appropriate symmetric generating set?

Comment: @Anirbit: If $G$ is abelian non-cyclic, than the girth is at most 4 because $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$ for every $a,b\in G$. If $G$ is metabelian, i.e. solvable of degree 2, then the girth is at most 16 because $[[a,b],[c,d]]=1$ for every $a,b,c,d\in G$. Etc...

Comment: ^Not getting you. Are these estimates independent of the choice of the generating set?

Comment: The Bourgain-Gamburd method can indeed give you some spectral-gap (not necessarily the real one, but some bound), but it depends on many many constants which appears in different stages as input (say some constants which appear inside the BGS lemma). You can look at some of the computations done by Kowalski here - https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/expander-graphs.pdf
You can try explicitly to compute it for say $SL_{2}(F_{p})$ and find out that you get spectral gap which is far below $3/16$.